# How can I use JPA do this SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria

Hello everyone I try do this query `"SELECT SUM(cevecoin) FROM coin where clid="ABC"` in JPA but it's no working. Can somebody help me?

```
public Integer SumCoin(String Clid) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder =getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<CoinBean> criteria =builder.createQuery(CoinBean.class);
    Root<CoinBean> root = criteria.from(CoinBean.class);
    criteria.select(builder.sum(root.<Integer>get("clid")).as(CoinBean.class)).where(builder.equal(root.get("clid"),Clid));
    return getSession().createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult().getCevecoin();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder =getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
// the type of query criteria must correspond to the result we want to obtain
CriteriaQuery<BigDecimal> criteria = builder.createQuery(BigDecimal.class);
Root<CoinBean> root = criteria.from(CoinBean.class);
// use multiselect and sum the field cevecoin
criteria.multiselect(builder.sum(root.get("cevecoin")))
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("clid"),Clid));

return getSession().createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: it's work think a lot. My method use Integer so I change BigDecimal to Integer .And thx for ur careful ,find "cevecoin" should be use ! THX.

Comment: In the end it is an approximation, the rates may vary. I recommend the use of metamodels to access the properties of the entities, which minimizes the probability of errors when constructing queries, since you can use autocomplete in your development environment and not put the properties as a string, which is susceptible to error.